# Order by with condition and with field

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to put the row that has scheduled date today with status 2 and if its not scheduled date today I want the result of status 1, 2, 3 base on created at. How can I put this on query?

**Here's example of the table**

```
table1
id | scheduled_date        | status | created_at
1  | null                  | 1      | 2021-12-20 00.00.00
2  | 2021-12-27 00.00.00   | 2      | 2021-12-19 00.00.00
3  | 2021-12-26 00.00.00   | 3      | 2021-12-23 00.00.00
4  | null                  | 1      | 2021-12-15 00.00.00
```

**Here's the query that I tried so far**

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
WHERE `status` <> 0
ORDER BY CASE WHEN date(scheduled_date) = '2021-12-27' AND status = 2 then 1 END ASC,
         FIELD(status, 1, 2, 3) ASC,
         `created_at` ASC
```

But I got the result of row `4,1,2,3` I want the result of row `2,4,1,3`

Any help will be appreciated. I'm also trying to do this on laravel so if its eloquent query is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually write the date 2021-12-27 unquoted?

Comment: yes I also tried quoted it but the result is same

Comment: *`... CASE WHEN date(scheduled_date) = 2021-12-27 and status = 2 then 1 END asc, ...`* You compare `date(scheduled_date)` and arithmetic expression `2021-12-27` = `1982`. Must be `... CASE WHEN date(scheduled_date) = '2021-12-27' and status = 2 then 1 END asc, ...`, read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: @Akina like I said it show the same result even if I quote it. anyway I will edit my post with quote

Comment: Since you are ordering the `CASE` in ascending order then the `null` that comes in the `ELSE` part (since you omitted the `ELSE` part) actually comes before the `1` of the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to put the row that has scheduled date today with status 2 and if its not scheduled date today I want the result of status 1, 2, 3 base on created at.

Test this

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DATE(scheduled_date) = '2021-12-27' AND status = 2 
              THEN 0
              ELSE status  -- or FIELD(status, 1, 2, 3)
              END,
         created_at
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use the boolean expression:

```
DATE(scheduled_date) = '2021-12-27' AND status = 2
```

in the `ORDER BY` clause and then simply `status` and `created_at`:

```
ORDER BY DATE(scheduled_date) = '2021-12-27' AND status = 2 DESC,
         status,
         created_at
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e4ed9edc329b5585566e929b3b49ed1).

Comment: The rows with NULL in `scheduled_date` will be placed last unconditionally... whereas OP needs them to be sorted according to the `status` value primarily, it seems.

Comment: @Akina check the demo I provided. Nulls are not positioned last unconditionally.

Comment: I'm having an error of `Unrecognized keyword. (near "status" at position 119)` I think this is not compatible on MySQL that I'm using

Comment: @Jovs I provided a demo where you can see the the code is valid MySql syntax. Are you sure that you are using the exact code?

Comment: Yes im using the exact code. After the `AND` I'm having the red underline on status means the syntax wont work. and I also tried to submit it

Comment: @Jovs I'm sure that you are doing something wrong. Post the code that you actually use.

Comment: ``select * from `table1` where `status` <> 0 ORDER BY DATE(scheduled_date) = '2021-12-27' AND status = 2 DESC,
         status,
         created_at``

Comment: Thas is the code that i use on your answer

Comment: Anyway I tried your answer with quote on status and it works. But I already tried akina answer and it works on the first try. I will still upvote this. Thank you.

Comment: I mean by quote is this '``'

Comment: @Jovs `status` is a keyword but not a reserved keyword: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S. It does not need backticks so it is odd that it works only with backticks.

Comment: *check the demo I provided* See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5d1aa5176bc6d41f1c51af5a939a8ea, especially the last row in the output...

Answer (score 1):

I think the nulls are causing the trouble here. Can you try the following

```
select *
  from `table1`
where `status` <> 0
order by CASE WHEN date(scheduled_date) = '2021-12-27' and status = 2 then 1 
              ELSE 2 
          END asc,
         FIELD(status, 1, 2, 3) asc,
         `created_at` asc
```