# Exclude condition in result

Tags: mysql

How do i exclude the condition in the Result?
I just want *Table_A.id* to be shown.

The query:

```
SELECT 
    Table_A.id,
    IF(Table_B.bbb > NOW(),
        Table_A.aaa,
        Table_B.bbb)
    AS to_order
FROM
    Table_A
        LEFT JOIN
    Table_B ON Table_A.id = Table_B.table_a_id
ORDER BY to_order DESC;
```

All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your condition to the `ORDER BY`-section and it should work.
Your query would look something like that:

```
SELECT 
Table_A.id
FROM
    Table_A
        LEFT JOIN
    Table_B ON Table_A.id = Table_B.table_a_id
ORDER BY 
    IF(Table_B.bbb > NOW(),
        Table_A.aaa,
        Table_B.bbb)
    AS to_order DESC;
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494561/order-by-with-condition-and-with-field).